# ILMerge throws System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, msbuild, signalr, dynamics-365, ilmerge

I am using SignalR, to display the data in real time from Dynamics 365  to a external web page.

I have create a plugin, which gets triggered in Post Create of my dummy entity.
I have reference to Micrisoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.

I used MSBuild.ILMerge.Task version 1.0.5. When i Rebuild the solution i get the message below.

> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: crmd.demo.signalr.dummy, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>   1>  Transitive merge
>   1>  Merged assemblies: C:\Test Folder\demo.signalr.dummy\demo.signalr.dummy\obj\Debug\demo.signalr.dummy.dll;C:\Test Folder\demo.signalr.dummy\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.2.4.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.dll;C:\Test Folder\demo.signalr.dummy\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll;
>   1>C:\Test Folder\demo.signalr.dummy\packages\MSBuild.ILMerge.Task.1.0.5\build\MSBuild.ILMerge.Task.targets(87,5): error : ILMerge.Merge:    There were errors reported in Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client's metadata.
>   1>C:\Test Folder\demo.signalr.dummy\packages\MSBuild.ILMerge.Task.1.0.5\build\MSBuild.ILMerge.Task.targets(87,5): error :   Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>   ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

I tried to look in the internet to find out whats causing this problem but i could not find any solution or article explaining why does it throw this error

> There were errors reported in Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client's metadata. 1>C:\Test Folder\demo.signalr.dummy\packages\MSBuild.ILMerge.Task.1.0.5\build\MSBuild.ILMerge.Task.targets(87,5): error : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

I would appreciate any help.

[image: Used Namespace]

Project References
[image]

Copy Local propertiy for Signal client set to true
[image]

Copy Local of Crm.Sdk.Proxy, Xrm.Sdk and System.IdentityModel are set to False.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That'd help us a great deal.

Comment: @WaiHaLee, Say someone in CRM creates a new record, I want that record to be available in company's website. So, I am using Signalr. And I have to add the reference to Signalr.client in my plugin. When I try to build the project after signing the dll I get this error thrown by MSBuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same problem and changing the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` version solved it!! 
We are using version 10.0.2.